# Mule: Error creating bean with name 'Secure_Property_Placeholder':

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am trying to use Secure Property Placeholder in mavenized project.
downloaded 1.3.3 secure property connector in anypoint.
loaded 1.3.3 maven dependency in pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

still getting below error:

Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Error creating bean with name 'Secure_Property_Placeholder': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mule/security/encryption/MuleEncryptionException
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an old version of the artifact.
Try using this instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>        
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if by adding the following dependencies to your POM file, the issue gets resolved?

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>security-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpg-jdk16</artifactId>
    <version>1.45</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-security-encryption</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>`
```

Comment: Only `mule-module-security-property-placeholder` should be required to get this working.

Comment: I have ran into this issue before, adding the above dependencies helped me fix it.

Comment: from which repo you got these artifacts.

i am using these


 <repositories>
          <repository>
            <id>Central</id>
            <name>Central</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

Comment: Can you try these? <repository>
<id>mulesoft-releases</id>
<name>MuleSoft Releases</name>
<url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>mule-ee-releases</id>
   <name>MuleEE Releases Repository</name>
   <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases-ee/
                     </url>
  </repository>
  <repository>
   <id>mulesoft-ee-release</id>
   <name>Mulesoft EE</name>
   <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus-ee/content/repositories/releases-ee/</url>
  </repository>

Comment: Thanks Abhay,
I added below repo and it worked like charm. 

        <repository>
            <id>mulesoft-master-releases</id>
            <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>